# After kernel update that begins with 5.14.15 (5.14.16 too) computer not booting (Fedora 35)

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, updates, kernel

But my notebook after the same update is working.

What to do?

Maybe I should report an error in kernel, but I don't know where it is to do.

My hardware:

- Motherboard – ASROCK A320M-HDV R4.0
- CPU – AMD Athlon 200GE 3.2 GHz
- RAM – DDR4 4 Gb Crucial 2666 MHz 1.2 V CL 19 CT4G4DFS8266
- HDD – 1000 Gb Toshiba P300

Comment: What _does_ it do?